# Как свернуть окно sfml?

Tags: c++, sfml

Вроде бы вопрос элементарнейший, но я нигде не могу найти на него ответа. Как же свернуть окно, созданное на sfml?

Comment: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24177.0

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает!

Comment: Вы можете дать ответ на собственный вопрос с помощью кнопки ниже. С примером кода, конечно, а не просто ссылкой